# Learning how to use build tools instead of an IDE. Confused on how debugging fits in

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build-process

When I'm using my IDE, I can write my source code, and press a button to build and debug my code, and have the ability to step through it.

But what is the workflow like when using a build tool along side of an IDE when it comes to debugging?  How do people generally debug their code in an IDE if they build their projects using a build tool?

I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

I'm using Eclipse and ANT if that matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse (and other IDEs) can attach to running Java processes, also if they are not started by the IDE. 
see [Attach debugger to application using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855520/attach-to-application-using-eclipse)

using `suspend=y` you can wait for the debugger to attach.

Comment: Does this still apply for a simple HelloWorld application that starts and finishes in under a second?

Comment: Interesting.  So the idea is to have a 'run-in-debug-mode' target in your build script, and then attach your IDE to it to start debugging?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to try this out.