# Remote Debugging in Eclipse/Intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea

Can I attach my eclise or Intellij Debugger to an already running remote application?

PS - I know how to remotely debug. But the key part here is that the application is already running and I don't know if the debug port was opened or not. And assuming that it wasn't, can anything be done about it? Or do I have to restart the application?

Just so the readers know, I have already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855520/attach-debugger-to-application-using-eclipse) post
and even though the answer is accepted, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Starting the app with debug options is required.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Are you sure about that? Because it looks like a delimitation to me. These would need a restart of my production app. What I had in mind was that I could debug probably a single thread and it wouldn't impact other users which are not using the resources used by that thread. Take a look at mko's answer for now.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that you can't get the full featured debugging without restarting the app with the debug options.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach debugger to running JVM process (that was not started with debug parameters) but you will have very limited options while in debug session.

Take a look here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html

*SA PID Attaching Connector*