# Debug java application in eclipse without using debugger

Tags: java, database, web-applications, execution

I am working on project that is not having debug options in eclipse.

I would like to understand the flow of execution from within Java classes across workspace.

Is there a method to understand the flow of execution. I am working on struts application and I have configured all dependant java files accordingly. But while running the application, new field added is not persisting to database and remains blank.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does "not having debug options" mean? We cannot suggest alternatives as long as we do not know what we are trying to avoid doing. For example, I would recommend that you [attach a debugger to the running application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6855747/7525132), but I do not know whether this is applicable in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

lazy way of debugging is by adding a print statement for every line you want to follow.
The right way would be using debug logs with Log4j